# How to generate tabs in Markdown

Tags: tabs, markdown, margin, indentation, tabular

I needed to adjust tables in a document, and I have to indent sort of them.
Apparently there is no way with native markdown syntax.

This is the result i want :

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MareksZirdzins i would just post my tips , no question !

Comment: @ChalkyWhite, if you want to share tips you still need to use the question and answer format. Up here you should ask your question and below you can add the answer part.

Answer (score 0):

The option I've found and I propose is to insert html in markdown.

Like this:

```
#### Title of tables  
<div style="margin-left: 5rem;">
<md>

First Table| Description |
- |:-: |
hey | hey yo
hey | hey yo
</md></div>

<div style="margin-left: 15rem;">
<md>

Table second| Description |
- |:-: |
hey | hey yo
hey | hey yo

</md></div>
```

Comment: Could you create something that shows this in action?